# C# - pass object with property changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass an object as parameter, but with it's property set at the same time. I had a code in ASP.NET MVC View:

```
@Html.PageLinks (Model.PagingInfo, x=> Url.Action("GetList", new {page = x}))
```

but I also need to pass Model.Filter

```
@Html.PageLinks (Model.PagingInfo, x=> Url.Action("GetList", Model.Filter))
```

this works, so I added Page property to class

The problem is to pass Model.Filter, but with ModelFilter.Page = x

Creating new object works, but Model.Filter has 10 properties and I need to rewrite each just to set Page property. I guess there must be more simple solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you not able to just set Model.Filter.Page value before passing it to the Url.Action, then pass the original Model.Filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Dirty Code*

```
@Html.PageLinks (Model.PagingInfo, x=> Url.Action("GetList", new List<Model.Filter>{Model.Filter}.Select(y => { y.Page = x; return y; }).FirstOrDefault();))
```